# Powershell - Getting values from JSON array return for specific row

Tags: powershell, rest, jira-rest-api, invoke-restmethod

Apologies for having to ask a question like this, self taught powershell user here.  Having an issue where I cannot seem to get the value I am after from a JSON return on a GET Invoke-RestMethod.

I am trying to pull JIRA ticket data so I can check to see if a custom field has been updated with a value.  I have tried calling the custom field directly in the response however due to way the response is formatted it will only return the column of data and therefore I am unable to use this reponse in my code.

My code is as follows:

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod "https://jira-ceg.atlassian.net/rest/servicedeskapi/request/$JIRATICKET" -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers 

$tester = $response.requestFieldValues


$tester
```

The response I get from JIRA is the following:

```
    fieldId           label              value                                                                                                                                                   
-------           -----              -----                                                                                                                                                   
summary           Summary            STAFF-NEW - XXXX- NAME 
customfield_10108 iTrent Information Employee ID: XXXX...                                                                                                                              
customfield_10086 Checklist Text     --- ERROR - No Role Entitlement Found - Contact Service Admin                                                                                           
description       Description        A new employee has joined. Please process with the data above.                                                                                          
customfield_10191 New AD Address     XXXX@XXXXX.com
```

I want to capture the value of the field customfield_10191, the field could sometimes be blank too, which I will test later in the script.  Any idea how I could do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$tester` is an object with properties `fieldId`,`label`, and `value`, you can use a combination of [member access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_properties?view=powershell-7) (syntax `object.property`) and [Where-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7):

```
($tester | Where fieldId -eq 'customfield_10191').value
```

[Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7) also works:

```
$tester | Where fieldId -eq 'customfield_10191' | Select-Object -Expand value
```

To return the object that contains the particular customer:

```
$tester | Where fieldId -eq 'customfield_10191'
```

Comment: Thank you!  I managed to get this working now using the select-object method.  I had issues with the header still coming through into the variable but found another article on here that mentioned -ft removeheader which solved my issue fully.  Thank you the script is now working perfectly!